# How to enforce an integer parameter to be a R resource id?

Tags: android

In Java, if you write

```
imageView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.abs__background_holo_dark);
```

Lint will tell you that you should pass a resolved color such as 0xAARRGGBB instead of R resource ID. How do they do that?

I would like to achieve the opposite: I would like to enforce an integer parameter to be strictly a R resource ID. Is the reverse possible?

Thank you.

Comment: You are using the wrong method: ImageView.setBackgroundColor is meant to be fed with an ARGB encoded color integer (and NOT a resource identifier number). ImageView.setBackgroundResource is probably the method you are looking for. However, there is no way to enforce the use of "R" resource identifiers over color integers since they are of the same type and Java cannot tell the difference.

Comment: Yes, I believe my 0xAARRGGBB is the ARGB encoded color integer you speak of. I am simply wondering is there a mechanism that can do these kind of enforcements; like @ nonnull or @ nullable, these are not standard Java but can still trigger lint messages to more efficiently guide other developers when using my API.

Comment: Given your example in your question, lint already does a pretty good job. It correctly identified that you were misusing the method "setBackgroundColor" by accidentally feeding it with a resource identifier instead of a color integer. Right now I'm not quite sure if I understand your question correctly, because you should have used setBackgroundResource instead setBackgroundColor. If you feel that some 'lint' feature is missing you could report it to the Android development team as a feature request: http://b.android.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The latest AppCompat libraries introduced Android Annotations](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/support-annotations), bundled as `support-annotations.jar`.

To enforce an integer parameter to be a R resource id, simply annotate the method declaration's parameter with @ColorRes, @LayoutRes, @DrawableRes, etc.